# Laravel dusk reports "General error: 5 database is locked" and "Operation timed out"

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I am running the script

```
namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class RegistrationTest extends DuskTestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */

    public function a_user_registers_for_an_account()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser)
        {
            $browser->visit(route('app-registration-create'))
                ->type('name', 'John')
                ->type('lastName', 'Doe')
                ->type('email', 'john.doe@ps.com')
                ->type('password', 'password')
                ->type('password_confirmation', 'password')
                ->click('@dusk-accept')
                ->click('@register-button') //
                ->assertDontSee('The name field is required.');
        });

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
            'email' => 'john.doe@ps.com',
            'verified' => 0
        ]);
    }


    /** @test */

    public function a_user_confirms_a_email_address()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser)
        {
            $user = User::where('email', 'john.doe@ps.com')->first();

            var_dump(route('app-registration-confirm-email', ['token' => $user->token])); // "http://ps.dev/app/registration/confirm/aPAWN1QlGyl8Id2vXIJU9Fn8G6bsef"

            $browser->visit(route('app-registration-confirm-email', ['token' => $user->token]));

        });

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
            'email' => 'john.doe@ps.com',
            'verified' => 1
        ]);
    }

}
```

and when it hits the line

```
$browser->visit(route('app-registration-confirm-email', ['token' => $user->token]));
```

it stops working. The idea behind that step is to verify that the user provided a valid e-mail address. Therefore the application will grab the token from the URL and check if there is a user in the database with that token. If so, set the verified property to 1 and set the token to null.

But I get the following errors:

Inside the laravel.log file I can see:

```
[2017-10-17 13:24:30] testing.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 
database is locked (SQL: update "users" set "verified" = 1, "token" = , 
"updated_at" = 2017-10-17 13:23:30 where "id" = 1)
```

On the terminal I can see:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\RegistrationTest::a_user_confirms_a_email_address
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http GET to /session/856dbb7e7769ec0a369e44e13b6b676d/screenshot

Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:286
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:535
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:333
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:244
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:160
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:341
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:161
/home/vagrant/ps/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:94
/home/vagrant/ps/tests/Browser/RegistrationTest.php:51
```

Maybe I don't apply dusk properly, but I couldn't find a solution on the web.

Answer (score 7):

This is a already somewhat old question but I found a solution to this problem when having it myself.
The problem was that the connection was not closed between tests. My tests would work if i would call only 1 at a time but running a batch of tests would throw the database locked error.

The solution was that I was missing the `parent::tearDown();` in my own teardown function. This means connections are not closed in between tests.

For the question that was asked there is most likely a `tearDown` function in the `DuskTestCase` or in another test without the `parent::tearDown();` in there. Check this out and you should be able to find the problem somewhere.

TLDR: Check your `tearDown` functions and make sure they contain the `parent::tearDown();`. Otherwise after a test the connection will not be closed.

Comment: Thanks man. You just saved me from days of debugging. Don't know how I missed this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using this line of code

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

in my setUp() method and this below in my tearDown() method

```
Artisan::call('migrate:rollback');
parent::tearDown();
```

I had to comment them out. Apparently the database connections are not closed in between tests and `RefreshDatabase` trait already takes care of this.